# how to add a block that only shows on home page

Tags: magento2, custom-block, home-page

I have created a block within my new theme, but it is showing on all pages, I need it to only show on the home page and when logging in or going to another page it does not show

create it inside default.xml

```
<container name="copyright.container" as="copyContainer" label="Copyright Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="copyright-container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="copyright__container" template="Magento_Cms::copy.phtml" />
</container>
```

on mi file .phtml

```
<div class="copy">
<span>
    <?php $Object = new DateTime();
        $anio = $Object->format("Y"); 
        echo "Copyright © $anio Agriconecta"; ?>  
</span>
```

I need it to only show on the home page and not on the other pages,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a block from Admin and then call it in your PHTML file

Admin > Content > Blocks > Add New Block

There you can add the html:

```
  <div class="copy">
<span>
   Copyright © 2021 Agriconecta.
</span> </div>
```

Then, in your PHTML file you call the block with this line:

```
<?= $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('HERETHEBLOCKIDENTIFIER')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: it works, but I don't get the styles I declare in app / design / frontend / Theme / Theme / Magento_Theme / web / css / source / _extend.css

Comment: _extend.css is an static file, so you have to create a new .Less file at web/css
then you have to import it in _extend.less as "@import '../_MyCssFile.less';"
After that, you must deploy static content "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"